# How to add regressors[xreg/newxreg] to a hierarchical time series forecast method[forecast.hts]?

Tags: hierarchy, time-series, forecasting

I'd like an example/method to incorporate regressors into forecast.hts. Below seems correct, but alas is not producing a forecast.

```
require(hts)
data(htseg2)
ri <- runif(14)
rix <- runif(16)
htseg2y <- hts(window(allts(htseg2),start = c(1992), end=c(2005))[,8:17],htseg2$g)
htseg2x <- hts((window(allts(htseg2),start = c(1992), end=c(2005))*ri)[,8:17],htseg2$g)
htseg2nx <- hts((window(allts(htseg2),start = c(1992), end=c(2007))*rix)[,8:17],htseg2$g)

forecast.hts(htseg2y , h = 2, fmethod = c("arima"), positive = F, stepwise=F,ic=c("bic"),level=4,trace=TRUE
             ,xreg = allts(htseg2x)
             ,newxreg = allts(htseg2nx))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchical time series `hts.mts` includes nine series. Your exogenous variable `hts.mtsx$y` contains eight series. You also use the same exogenous series for the historical data as for the future data.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Created two sets of exogenous, one for the model and one for prediction and captured the nine series from both, but remain stuck. 
Would welcome an alternative example, anything would be better than my stumbling.